# Twitter Quick Replies - Twitter4J (Java) Example

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Does anybody know if there is a support in Twitter4J (or a Java dependency) for Quick replies?  I recently read that Twitter will support messanger-customizations ([link](https://techcrunch.com/2017/06/13/twitter-chatbots-can-now-add-buttons-that-push-you-to-tweet-follow-click-more)), like Facebook (persistent menus, button templates) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a brand new API from Twitter, so at the moment there are few client libraries that directly support these new features through interfaces and methods. Twitter4J has no specific support for the new API endpoints and formats, but in theory you could modify or extend the existing Direct Message support in Twitter4J to enable that.

Twitter has an [end-to-end sample](https://github.com/twitterdev/twitter-webhook-boilerplate-node) for the new Account Activity API webhooks and the new Direct Message formats written in node.js, if you are interested in adapting something.